# My dragon masks are flipped sideways

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

For some reason, Dukaan and Ahzidal are flipped forward so you can't see the fronts on the dragon priest display in Heindhelm. Any fixes?

I'm playing the Anniversary Edition on Xbox.

Comment: Are you using any mods?